# Can't Connect with Mysql database in Android

Tags: android, mysql, httpurlconnection

I was trying to insert data into the database. For that i am using `HTTPURLConnection`. But I am not getting any values in `conn2.getOutputStream()`.

```
try {
    HashMap < String, String > cc = checkdata(hm);
    Sendmail(cc);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(cc);


    url2 = new URL("http://192.168.1.99/mist/app/inserttask.php");
    conn2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();

    conn2.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn2.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn2.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn2.setDoInput(true);
    conn2.setDoOutput(true);


    Uri.Builder builder3 = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("tasklist", "hai");
    String query1 = builder3.build().getEncodedQuery();
    Log.e("eeeor3", query1);
    OutputStream os2 = conn2.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os2, "UTF-8"));
    //Log.e("eeeor1",query1);
    writer2.write(query1);
    Log.e("eeeor", "written");
    writer2.flush();
    writer2.close();
    os2.close();
    conn2.connect();


} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() + " is Mandatory..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're running this code on the ui thread. Try to use `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: my code is not running after  OutputStream os2 = conn2.getOutputStream();

Comment: Do you get any errors/exceptions? Check your logcat.

Comment: Maybe you're running this code on the ui thread. Try to use `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: Updates my answer with the solution. Please accept it ;)